# (ANGULARJS) Input[time] is showing local time when given a regular date

Tags: angularjs, input, time, momentjs

Basically,

I received a date from my server which is, when printed out in the web console, this : **Date 2016-05-04T09:00:00.000Z**

Since, im using AngularJs, I did a binding using ng-model with an input time type.

Now the problem, is when ever I show the date in that input, I dont see: 
**9:00**, but **5:00** *(9:00 - 4:00)* (I'm in a GMT -4 zone)

However the date isn't supposed to be a Universal Time, but as you can see it is parsed to local time. Any way to stop this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The time zone to be used to read/write the Date instance in the model can be defined using ngModelOptions. By default, this is the timezone of the browser. [AngularJS API input[time]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D)

In your case the following option should do the trick.

```
<input type="time" ng-model-options="{ timezone: '-0400' }">
```

But beware with this option you are overwriting the browser's timezone. That means if a user operates in UTC+2 the input time is still treated as UTC-4.

Comment: Cool & interesting +1, what will happen in case of internationalization?